# Send array of MultipartBody by retrofit

Tags: java, android, api, web-services, retrofit

I can send one MultipartBody which contain 3 image and some attribute as the following

Interface:

```
@POST("test_request")
Call<ResponseBody> test(@Body RequestBody file);
```

code :

```
  private MultipartBody getMultiFile(CoursesAdded coursesAdded) {

    ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();

    filePaths.add(coursesAdded.getImag1());
    filePaths.add(coursesAdded.getImag2());
    filePaths.add(coursesAdded.getImag3());


    MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder();
    builder.setType(MultipartBody.FORM);


    builder.addFormDataPart("skill", coursesAdded.getCourse_name());
    builder.addFormDataPart("certificate_from",    coursesAdded.getCourse_location());
    builder.addFormDataPart("certificate_date", "null");

    for (int i = 0; i < filePaths.size(); i++) {
        File file = new File(filePaths.get(i));
        builder.addFormDataPart("file[]", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file));
    }

    MultipartBody requestBody = builder.build();
    return requestBody;

}
```

But now I need to send array of MultipartBody.

get Array function:

```
   private MultipartBody[] getArray() {

        MultipartBody[] multipartBodies = new MultipartBody[coursesAddedArrayList.size()];


        for (int i = 0; i < coursesAddedArrayList.size(); i++) {

            CoursesAdded coursesAdded = new CoursesAdded(
                    coursesAddedArrayList.get(i).getCourse_name(),
                    coursesAddedArrayList.get(i).getCourse_location(),
                    coursesAddedArrayList.get(i).getImag1(),
                    coursesAddedArrayList.get(i).getImag2(),
                    coursesAddedArrayList.get(i).getImag3()
            );

            multipartBodies[i] = getMultiFile(coursesAdded);
        }

        return multipartBodies;

    }
```

Interface:

```html
    @POST("test_request")
    Call<ResponseBody> addCourses(
            @Body MultipartBody[] requestsBody
            );
```

when display the request in response to see what was sent I got the following

> [size=1838 text={"test":[{"boundary":{"data":[55,48,99,55,97,56,52,53,45,101,97,…]

Comment: This may help. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-a-dynamic-amount-of-files-to-server

Comment: MultipartBody.Part can send one image , but in my case each MultipartBody is content 3 Part and some other attribute